# python pandas: assigning a json data to a data frame entry returns error "Incompatible indexer with Series"

Tags: json, pandas, jsonb

As a newbie to python I'm struggling with an error "Incompatible indexer with Series".

I'm reading a  entry from a postgreSQL database:

```
    df_postgresDB = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM public.json_view',con=<...>)        
    exampleKey = 'FPB-83160'
    jsonCol = 'efforts'
    AreasDict = df_postgresDB.loc[exampleKey, jsonCol]
    print('AreasDict=', AreasDict)
    print('type(AreasDict)=', type(AreasDict))
```

...output:

```
    AreasDict= {'4G NeVe': 0, '4G FT ET': 400, '4G C-Plane': 800, 'MANO BTSSM': 0}
    type(AreasDict)= <class 'dict'>
```

The column in the postgreSQL data base shows type 'jsonb':

[image]

This 'AreasDict' is used in the function of another project I want to call and re-use for my project. But in my project, I need to build up the data from another source. So I create a data frame and try to assign that 'AreasDict' ()...

```
    column_names = ['issue_key', jsonCol]
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(1,2), columns=column_names)
    df.iloc[0, 0] = exampleKey
    df.iloc[0, 1] = AreasDict
```

... and with the last code line I get that error

> ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Problem is in pandas is not recomended store dicts in DataFrame column, but one possible solution is use `df.iloc[0, 1] = [AreasDict]`

Comment: Yes, that turns it into class 'list' !!
I'll try that in my project that calls the function using it and let you know.

Comment: So it working for you nice? It is what you need?

Comment: I still have to try that principle in my 'real' project that calls the shared function and see if that function eats it.Will let you know.

Comment: IT WORKS! You made my day, jezrael!
... and off to the next hick-up...

Comment: Unfortunately I need to revise my previous statement: 
`df.iloc[0, 1] = [AreasDict]`certainly converts the dict to list.
But the shared function doesn't eat the list as dict.
To my surprise the very first 
   `df.iloc[0, 1] = [AreasDict]`
in the big loop assigned a dict into the data frame (that caused the 'hurray!'.
But the very next really put a list in, noit a dict anymore.

Comment: so it not working gfor your solution?

Comment: @jezrael: no. but I found agreement with the developer of the share function to do this: 
`if isinstance(AreasDict, str) :` and 
`AreasDict = ast.literal_eval(AreasDict)`.

Comment: So set string t column and then convert it to dict? Like `df.iloc[0, 1] = str(AreasDict)` and then `df[jsonCol] = df[jsonCol].apply(ast.literal_eval)` ?

Comment: @jezrael: I have no clue why it worked for the very first instance bt not for the rest. It had something to do how I added the column (df['efforts'] = np.nan) first. Once I changed that to df = df.assign(efforts="") also the very first instance became a list, not a dict.

it's not your fault, your assignment works. it just doen't put a a dict into the dataframe column.

Comment: I think try `df['efforts'] = [{}]` - there should be some implicit conversion.

Comment: if I try dfJson.loc[row['issue_key'], 'jsnEfforts'] = [{s1}] with s1 being a string I get entries like [{'{"HW_IV": 1.0}'}] - i.e. not what's needed.
Never mind!

Comment: The workaround (5 comments up) is ok for me and the developer of the shared function is ok as well.

Comment: Do you think `if isinstance(AreasDict, str) : and AreasDict = ast.literal_eval(AreasDict)` or `df.iloc[0, 1] = str(AreasDict) df[jsonCol] = df[jsonCol].apply(ast.literal_eval)` ?

Comment: the workaround?
this one: `if isinstance(AreasDict, str) : then AreasDict = ast.literal_eval(AreasDict`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas non scalar values are poorly supported - many function should failed.

---

Solution is convert to `list` for list of dictionary:

```
jsonCol = 'j'
exampleKey = 'key'
AreasDict= {'4G NeVe': 0, '4G FT ET': 400, '4G C-Plane': 800, 'MANO BTSSM': 0}

column_names = ['issue_key', jsonCol]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(1,2), columns=column_names)
df.iloc[0, 0] = exampleKey
df.iloc[0, 1] = [AreasDict]
print (df)
  issue_key                                                  j
1       key  [{'4G NeVe': 0, '4G FT ET': 400, '4G C-Plane':...
```